# Store page urls by customised javascript

Tags: javascript

Master template TMPL includes page1, page2, page3 and so on, 
I want to record each visited page from client side, then store them as an array variable;

for example the visitor opened below URLs:

http://www.myweb.com/page1/,  http://www.myweb.com/page2/, http://www.myweb.com/page8/

I want my Array to be `['http://www.myweb.com/page1/', 'http://www.myweb.com/page2/'`, 'http://www.myweb.com/page8/'];

```
var pageArray = [],
    viewedPage;

var pageREM = () => {
    viewedPage = location.href;
    pageArray.push(viewedPage);
    return pageREM();
}

pageREM();
```

I return the fucntion itself I suppose it can add the value each visit. 
However, I am getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

Answer (score 0):

You have the choice between using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

**localStorage:**

```
myStorage = localStorage;
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

**Cookies:**

```
document.cookie = "favorite_food=tripe";
```